# comma separated column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to take the values from 3 columns and group them into 1 column as comma separated:

```
2014-01-01,2014-01-29
```

The problem is that one or more columns can be NULL and therefore it messes up the commas as such:

```
2014-01-01,,2014-01-29
```

This is how I have it coded (the case statement basically just strips out a comma if it's the last character in the string.

I need to add some logic so that it takes into account NULLs but I'm having a hard time coming up with it.

```
CASE WHEN RIGHT(ISNULL(d.FirstGapDate + ',', '') + ISNULL(d.PayrollGapDate + ',', '') + d.LastGapDate, 1) = ',' 
     THEN LEFT(ISNULL(d.FirstGapDate + ',', '') + ISNULL(d.PayrollGapDate + ',', '') + d.LastGapDate, LEN(ISNULL(d.FirstGapDate + ',', '') + ISNULL(d.PayrollGapDate + ',', '') + d.LastGapDate) - 1)
     ELSE ISNULL(d.FirstGapDate + ',', '') + ISNULL(d.PayrollGapDate + ',', '') + d.LastGapDate
END AS AlLGapDatesFormatted
```

EDIT -

I need to group the highlighted (notice that PayrollGapDate is ''):

[image]

And this is what I'm getting:

[image]

And this is the code I implemented:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this to yourself? Storing data like that violates 1NF and causes nothing but pain.

Comment: There are [several](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20split%20string) examples of how to split a string in sql server.  Have you tried any of them?  (also +1 to @SeanLange's comment, change your data)

Comment: @xQbert: That only solves it in the specific case of only the middle value being null. There are six other possible cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: All, I'm not storing this data. It's a report that needs to have this "calculated" column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using this technique:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON  --<<<make sure concatenations with NULL result in NULL

DECLARE @C1 varchar(10)='AAA'
       ,@C2 varchar(10)='BBB'
       ,@C3 varchar(10)=null
       ,@C4 varchar(10)='DDD'

SELECT  STUFF(    ISNULL(', '+@C1,'')
                 +ISNULL(', '+@C2,'')
                 +ISNULL(', '+@C3,'')
                 +ISNULL(', '+@C4,'')

                 ,1,2,''
             )
```

output:

```
-----------------------------------------------
AAA, BBB, DDD

(1 row(s) affected)
```

You let the `', '+@C3` result in NULL, which the `ISNULL(***,'')` converts to empty string.  The `STUFF(***,1,2,'')` removes the leading comma and space.

try:

```
SELECT  STUFF(    ISNULL(', '+d.FirstGapDate,'')
                 +ISNULL(', '+d.PayrollGapDate,'')
                 +ISNULL(', '+d.LastGapDate,'')

                 ,1,2,''
             )
    FROM ...
    WHERE...
```

Comment: KM, take a look at my edit. I implemented what you said but I'm still having an issue in the middle field.

Comment: Never mind. I made it so that it comes in as NULL (if it's NULL, rather than '')

Answer (score 1):

You can apply something like this above your expression to replace many commas with one comma:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = 'ABC,,,,DEF'

select replace(replace(replace(@s, ',', '[]'), '][', ''), '[]', ',')
```